# How to write less boilerplate in a expression evaluator written with recursion-schemes

Tags: haskell, syntax, boilerplate, recursion-schemes

With the [recursion-scheme](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes) library 
it's easy to write abstract syntax trees and the corresponding expression evaluators:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable 
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH

data Expr  = Plus Expr  Expr 
           | Mult Expr Expr 
           | Const Expr 
         deriving (Show, Eq)
makeBaseFunctor ''Expr  
-- Write a simple evaluator
eval :: Expr -> Int 
eval = cata alg 
  where 
    alg = \case
      PlusF  x y  -> (+) x y
      MultF  x y  -> (*) x y
      ConstF x    -> x
```

Now look at the case in the `alg` function in the where clause of `eval`. I think all the `x` and `y` variables 
should not be necessary. Therefore I'm looking for some way (a syntax, a language extension etc.)
to remove this boilerplate and just to write:

```
  PlusF  -> (+)
  MultF  -> (*)
  ConstF -> id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could refactor your language to have binary operations on one hand and unary ones on the other. You'd write:

```
data BinOp = PlusOp | MultOp deriving (Show, Eq)
data UnOp  = ConstOp deriving (Show, Eq)

data Expr  = Bin BinOp Expr  Expr
           | Un  UnOp  Expr
         deriving (Show, Eq)
makeBaseFunctor ''Expr
```

The evaluator then becomes:

```
eval :: Expr -> Int
eval = cata $ \case
  BinF op l r -> bin op l r
  UnF  op v   -> un op v
  where
    bin = \case
      PlusOp -> (+)
      MultOp -> (*)

    un = \case
      ConstOp -> id
```

Answer (score 3):

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/catamorphism-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Morphism-Cata.html derives a catamorphism for `ExprF`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Data.Functor.Foldable 
import Data.Functor.Foldable.TH
import Data.Morphism.Cata

data Expr 
  = Plus Expr Expr 
  | Mult Expr Expr 
  | Const Expr 
  deriving (Show, Eq)
makeBaseFunctor ''Expr
$(makeCata defaultOptions ''ExprF)

-- Write a simple evaluator
eval :: Expr -> Int 
eval = cata $ exprF (+) (*) id
```

Note that it can also derive a catamorphism for `Expr`, yielding `eval = expr (+) (*) id` and letting you skip `Data.Functor.Foldable.TH` for this specific usecase.

Comment: Personally, I don't like `exprF (+) (*) id` way of calling function. Looks error-prone because it's easy to mess up parameters (swap `+` and `*`). Specifying explicitly mapping from constructor to functions looks better to me.